# Comprendiendo Guzzle: error que no comprendo

Tags: php, guzzle

Estoy intentando convertir un código  que funciona, a su versión con Guzzle, pero no obtengo el resultado deseado, y creo que es por una falta de comprensión de Guzzle v6.

Si yo ejecuto el código siguiente

```php
$postfields = array(
    'identifier' => $this->username,
    'secret' => $this->password,
    'accesskey' => $this->accesskey,
    'action' => 'GetClients',
    'responsetype' => self::RESPONSE_TYPE,
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url.self::ENDPOINT);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postfields));

$response = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_error($ch)) {
    die('Unable to connect: ' . curl_errno($ch) . ' - ' . curl_error($ch));
}

curl_close($ch);

// Decode response
$jsonData = json_decode($response, true);
```

Pero si lo paso a su modelo (el que yo pienso) falla.

```php
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$response = $client->post($this->url.self::ENDPOINT, [
    'headers' => [
        'action' => 'GetClients',
        'identifier' => $this->username,
        'secret' => $this->password,
        'accesskey' => $this->accesskey,
        'responsetype' => self::RESPONSE_TYPE
    ]
]);
```

Alcanzo una excepción

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException  : Client error: `GET https://mydomain.com/intranet/includes/api.php` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
result=error;message=Invalid IP 2.137.XXX.XX
```

Por otro lado no se como entender la llamada (url que forma Guzzle) con el método -get()

Answer (score 2):

El error es de cajón desastre. Un mal entendimiento de Guzzle, me llevo a usar `headers`en lugar de `form_params` en el método `post`

```
$response = $client->post($this->url.self::ENDPOINT, [
    'form_params' => [
        'action' => 'GetClients',
        'identifier' => $this->username,
        'secret' => $this->password,
        'accesskey' => $this->accesskey,
        'responsetype' => self::RESPONSE_TYPE
    ]
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
$headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
$headers['Authorization'] = 'f51sd56f1s1f56';
$method = 'POST'
$requestUrl = 'http://localhost:2222/Actualizaryyyy'
$reqParamArray = array();
$reqParamArray['codigo'] = $request->codigo;

    $response = $client->request($method, $requestUrl, ['form_params' => $reqParamArray,'query' => $queryParam, 'headers' => $headers]);
    return $response->getBody()->getContents()
```

;